# Creating a 'grid' of instanecs of a class in Python

Tags: python, list, grid

I've been using this site a lot for finding answers to my various programming questions, and I firstly want to thank you all for the tons of help you've been throughout my journey of programming. Anyway, off to my question:

I want to create a list of lists of instances of a class. Wow, that was a mouthful. Let me try to explain better in code. For example, the following 3x3 'grid':

```
foo = [bar(), bar(), bar()],
       bar(), bar(), bar()],
       bar(), bar(), bar()]]
```

Which works perfectly, however, I don't know the dimensions of the 'grid' beforehand. In my mind, the most logical attempt was to do the following:

```
foo = [[bar()]*num]*num
```

However, this does not work properly. I believe the error is that Python is populating the 'grid' full of the same instance of bar(), which is problematic. Is there any way 'nice' that I can complete this task of filling a grid with different instances of bar()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo = [[bar() for _ in xrange(num)] for _ in xrange(num)]
```

Sequence multiplication makes a big grid of references to the same object. You need to use list comprehensions to evaluate the `bar()` expression repeatedly.

Comment: In modern Pythons, `range` has the same behavior as `xrange`, so in general you should prefer `range`, as using `xrange` just drives up the noise in your code.

Comment: @RafeKettler: That only applies to Python 3, in which `xrange` doesn't even exist. Currently, when the version is unspecified, the default assumption is Python 2.